# onMapReady Marker does not work

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

i Have a `Fragment` that should show a Specific place on `Google Map`

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
public ContactFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    FragmentManager fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    final SupportMapFragment myMAPF = (SupportMapFragment) fragment.findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng marker = new LatLng(34.877737,-1.326545);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker,13));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker));
}
}
```

and in the XML file of the Fragment i have this :

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact_domiciliation"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    ></fragment>
```

Yet when i launch click on the button that opens this fragment i get a map of the entire globe .

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to the fragment:

```
myMAPF.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference a Runtime Exception

Comment: did u use it after declaring `SupportMapFragment myMAPF`

Comment: that's what i've done actually , still gave me this exception whenever i open this fragment on the app and it cashes